# tesseract api with load_system_dawg and load_freq_dawg

Tags: c++, tesseract

How to set `load_system_dawg` and `load_freq_dawg` to `false` ??

I need to disable the dictionary.. So I guess these are the two parameteres I need to set to false?

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
if(api->Init(NULL, "dan+eng")){
    // error
}
api->SetImage(image);
api->Recognize(0);
```

tesseract `3.05.01`

Answer (score 2):

1. In your `tessdata` directory create a `configs` directory
2. Create a file config (you will pass name of config file later in code)
3. Fill your config file with following text

> ```
> load_system_dawg     F    
> load_freq_dawg       F
> ```

4. Modify your code

   ```
   auto     numOfConfigs = 1;
   auto     **configs    = new char *[numOfConfigs];
   configs[i] = (char *) "name of your config file";

   tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
   if(api->Init(NULL, "dan+eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT, configs, numOfConfigs, nullptr, nullptr, false)){
       // error
   }
   ```

P.S. It is also possible to do with last couple of arguments of Init function, feel free to try them out yourself.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution where I don't need to create any additional files.. but do it directly from the code

Comment: As i said you can use last couple arguments (`const GenericVector<STRING> *vars_vec,const GenericVector<STRING> *vars_values`) to do the same thing. It is unclear from your question whether you don't want to create additional files and why not.

Comment: Could you please show me an example? I'm not familiar with C++ or C in general

Comment: It would be helpful if this answer showed a full code-only implimentation. I'm working on Kaggle and I can't access the config file.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the following link:
[enter link description here](http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-ocr-parameters-in-302-version)

search for load_system_dawg in the document.

It says that a value of 1 will load the dictionaries, similarly for load_freq_dawg.

Using a value of 0 = false, we can disable frequency words and the dictionary as follows:

```
//pseudo code
api.setVariable("load_system_dawg","0");
api.setVariable("load_freq_dawg","0");
```

Comment: according to https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ControlParams
these variables are init only variables, so this won't work (and I personaly can confirm it won't as I tried)