# Can I switch the PyTesseract configuration mid script?

Tags: python, configuration, ocr, python-tesseract

I have a lot of success locating dictionary keywords like "Document", or "Description" on screenshots that I take, but I do not have success with non-dictionary words such as document names. These non-dictionary words are usually a random string of letters and words; for example, "FX89349".

I am currently using PyTesseract, and I understand that I can change the configuration to detect non-dictionary words, but that would require me to change my configuration mid script since I also have to search for dictionary words. From my research, I'm not sure if this is possible.

Below is a snippet of my code that involves the OCR. I take a screenshot, and then look for a keyword to move forward with some preprocessing in between.

```
def OCRscreen(keyword, justCaseCheck):
    # One can just type 'OCRscreen( <WORD YOU'RE LOOKING FOR> )' to find its coordinates
    # Put TRUE after if you just want to check if a case is present
    # Put FALSE if this is a dire check for a keyword
    
    print(f"We are currently searching for the keyword '{keyword}' ")

    # Number of attempts of looking for keyword
    numTries = 0        # keeps track of the number of times 

    # So that waste less time if the case isn't there
    if justCaseCheck == True:
        maxNumTries = 2
    else:
        maxNumTries = 5        # increased because sometimes we need to wait for the page to load

    # OCR logic
    while True:
        pyautogui.screenshot('imageToOCR.png')     # taking screenshot of desktop

        #have Tesseract read it and convert to GRAY SCALE
        readImage = cv2.imread('imageToOCR.png')        
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(readImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Binarize it
        thresh = 255 - cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]      # using Otsu's threshold to binarize foreground from background

        #Write GRAY SCALE image to disk as a temp file to OCR it
        tempFile = "{}.png".format(os.getpid() )
        cv2.imwrite(tempFile, thresh) # gray)

        results = pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open(tempFile), lang='eng', config='--psm 11', output_type=Output.DICT)       
        # print(results["text"])

        # Checks to see if our keyword showed up on screen
        if keyword not in results["text"]:
            print("Attempted without blur. Now trying a blurred image... ")
            time.sleep(1)
            numTries += 1
            pyautogui.move(200,200)

            # Try blurring this time
            blurredImage = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3,3), 0)     # blur before processing
            tempFile_Blur = "{}.png".format(os.getpid() )
            cv2.imwrite(tempFile_Blur, blurredImage)
            results_Blur = pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open(tempFile_Blur), lang='eng', config='--psm 6', output_type=Output.DICT)


            if keyword not in results_Blur["text"]:
                # Different print messages depending on whether it's just a check or not 
                if justCaseCheck == True:
                    print(f"Identifier '{keyword}' was not found. Trying again. This is attempt {numTries}. After {maxNumTries} attempts the case will be accepted as absent. ")                    
                else:
                    print(f"Identifier '{keyword}' was not found. Trying again. This is attempt {numTries}. After {maxNumTries} attempts the script will stop. ")
                time.sleep(0.5)


            if numTries == maxNumTries:
                print(f"We have reached {maxNumTries} attempts. \n")

                if justCaseCheck == True:
                    return      # would return None if it's not found. 
                                    # If we DID find it, then it would return the coordinates
                elif justCaseCheck == False:
                    input("We are either not on the correct page, or OCR has failed to find our keyword. Script will now exit. ")
                    exit()

        elif keyword in results["text"] or keyword in results_Blur["text"]:
            break
                        
    keywordToString = str(keyword) # changing keyword to String

    # Checking for the keyword in the results BEFORE WE MOVE ON
    if keywordToString not in results["text"]:
        print("Didn't find keyword on screen.")
        input('Press ENTER to exit now. ')
        exit()
    
    #Get the index number of the results to grab the coordinates of the keyword
    for i in range(0, len(results["text"]) ):
        if keywordToString in results["text"][i]:

            #Setting coordinates
            x = results["left"][i]
            y = results["top"][i]
            w = results["width"][i]
            h = results["height"][i]

            # Grabbing coordinates for the center of the keyword
            center_x = x + w/2      # By adding half the width we go halfway of the width of the word
            center_y = y + h/2      # By subtracting half of the height (since we grab the y from the top L corner of the word) we go to halfway point of its height
            # print(f"y = {y}") 
            # print(f"center_y = {center_y} \n")

    #
    # Delete temp file afterwards
    #os.remove(tempFile)
    print("Found it! ") 
    return center_x, center_y
#
# End of OCR function
```

I would appreciate any insight on how I might overcome this problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want to be able to switch between searching for dictionary words, and a string of random numbers and letters. I know one way is to change the configuration of PyTesseract by setting load_punc_dawg and load_freq_dawg to false, but I'm not sure how to execute that in my code, or how to switch them back to true after I found the string of random numbers and letters.

Comment: standard `tesseract` can run `tesseract imagefile configfile` so maybe you could  run `PyTesseract.image_to_string(..., config="configfile")` and use two different config files to run it with different parameters. And if you need other options then `config="--psm 6 configfile"`

Comment: I want to try and do it within the code, which seems possible according to this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204628/tesseract-api-with-load-system-dawg-and-load-freq-dawg), but I'm not sure how this would translate to Python... would you happen to know?

Ideally, I can make my OCRscreen() function go between the 2 configurations with such a method.

Comment: first answer in your link use method which I described in my previous comment - it uses config file with different values. SO if you use `config=first_config_file`  in one `image_to_string` and later `config=other_config_file` in other `image_to_string` then you will run with different settings. As I found there is no method to change these values directly in code.